# Why does only GET request work on frontend. POST, PUT, and Delete won't work

Tags: javascript, http-post, fetch, postman, crud

I have a java servlet CRUD app. GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE work when I use postman. But when I use my front end javascript code only the GET request will work. POST, PUT, and DELETE methods on servlet backend are being reached but its seems no parameters are attached to the request when it reaches the backend.

Below is my GET JS code.

```
function getTimePeriods(){
    clearElements()
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/TimeTrackerWServlets/TimePeriodController/'

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => showTimePeriods(response))     
}
```

Below is the POST JS code.

```
function post(){
    console.log("post file reached")
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/TimeTrackerWServlets/TimePeriodController/'
    const Data = {
        timePeriodId: "999",
        activityType: "ANIME"
    };

    const otherPram = {
        headers: {
            "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF - 8"
        },
        body : Data,   //JSON.stringify(Data)
        method: "POST",
        // mode: "no-cors",
    };

    fetch(url, otherPram)
    .then(data=>{return data.json})
    .then(res=>console.log(res))
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
```

I can console.log the object I want to attached to the request fine.

Below is an abbreviated version of my servlet doPost method.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("doPost reached POST POST POST POST POST POST POST POST ");
        setAccessControlHeaders(response);

        System.out.println("startTime: " + request.getParameter("timePeriodId"));
        System.out.println("startTime: " + request.getParameter("activityType"));
    }
```

Both

```
System.out.println("startTime: " + request.getParameter("timePeriodId")); ---> null
System.out.println("startTime: " + request.getParameter("activityType")); ---> null
```

print out null.

So how do I attach the data to the request on the front end. Your my only hope Obi-Wan Kenobi.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding using JSON.stringify on your data object might be the issue, aswell as passing wrong parameters on "Content-type" header,

Edit:

Try with these settings:

```
function post(){
    console.log("post file reached")
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/TimeTrackerWServlets/TimePeriodController/'

    const otherPram = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept':'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        body : "timePeriodId=999&activityType=ANIME",
        method: "POST",
    };

    fetch(url, otherPram)
    .then(data=>{return data.json})
    .then(res=>console.log(res))
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
```

Comment: I changed body to use JSON.stringify and added Accept to the headers. Can't get parameters on backend yet.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `charset` from your `content-type` header and re-replacing the JSON stringify fixes it.

```
function post(){
    console.log("post file reached")
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/test123'
    const Data = {
        timePeriodId: "999",
        activityType: "ANIME"
    };
    const otherPram = {
        headers: {
            "content-type" : "application/json"
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(Data),
        method: "POST",
        // mode: "no-cors",
    };
    fetch(url, otherPram)
        .then(data=>{return data.json})
        .then(res=>console.log(res))
        .catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
```

Comment: I removed the charset and put back stringify. No parameters on the backend yet.

Comment: This code doesn't submit params, it submits a body. Are you checking for a body? If your backend is express, use `console.log(req.body)`